# SQL Converting int to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I need help converting an `integer` to a `varchar`.

I'm trying to write a procedure that takes in a `ProfileID` and a `Currenttime`; using those  two values it finds the start time of the `profileID` and subtracts `currenttime` from 
`starttime` and returns `hours:minutes:seconds`.

What am I doing wrong, is there a better way to write this?

Thanks.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalculateElaspedTime]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ProfileID nvarchar(10),
    @CurrentDateTime datetime = '' 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    if @CurrentDateTime = CAST('' as datetime)
    set @CurrentDateTime = GETDATE()

    DECLARE @StartTime datetime;
    DECLARE @ElaspedTime time;
    DECLARE @hh int;
    DECLARE @mm int;
    DECLARE @ss int;
    Declare @TimeString varchar
    set @StartTime = (Select top 1 [DateTime] From Log WHERE ProfileID = @ProfileID);
    set @hh = DateDiff(hour,@StartTime,@CurrentDateTime);
    set @mm = DateDiff(minute,@StartTime,@CurrentDateTime)-60*@hh;
    set @ss = DateDiff(second,@StartTime,@CurrentDateTime)-60*@mm;

    set @TimeString = (Select CAST(@hh as varchar)); -- Fails Here 
    set @ElaspedTime = convert(datetime, cast(@hh as varchar) + ':' + cast(@mm as varchar) + ':' + cast(@ss as varchar));
    INSERT INTO Log (ElaspedTime) Values (@ElaspedTime);
END
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: What is the value of @hh at the point the error occurs?  As an aside, your logic for ElapsedTime suggests that you are not referring to the interval.

Comment: The value of @hh = 1. Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: cast(@hh as varchar) could not be evaluated

Comment: Have you tried using nvarchar(10) in place of a varchar with an unspecified length?

Comment: You could give a try with this:
cast(@hh as varchar(32))

Comment: Yes and im seeing the same error

Comment: SELECT cast(@hh as nvarchar) + ':' + cast(@mm as nvarchar) + ':' + cast(@ss as nvarchar); this works but some reason the convert isn't working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this.  All of that excitement in the function may be unnecessary.

```
CONVERT(varchar(10),(@CurrentDateTime-@Start_Time),108)
```

Comment: You should **always** specify a **length** for your `varchar` when converting to it. Do you know what the default is if you omit the length?

Answer (score 1):

One problem you have is this statement:

```
set @StartTime = (Select top 1 [DateTime] From Log WHERE ProfileID = @ProfileID);
```

Its results are indeterminate as SQL makes no guarantees about result order unless you explicitly specify it in an ORDER BY clause. You should be using ORDER BY or using an aggregate function like MAX() to get the row you want.

And you're doing a lot more work than necessary. SQL Server (recent versions, anyway) support date arithmetic, with the result of subtracting two dates being another date (offset from the SQL Server epoch of 1 Jan 1900 00:00:00.000. This simpler form ought to do you, unless the elapsed time will exceed 1 day:

```
create procedure dbo.CalculateElaspedTime

  @ProfileID       nvarchar(10)  ,
  @CurrentDateTime datetime = '' 

as

  set nocount on

  declare
    @now     dateTime    ,
    @start   datetime    ,
    @elapsed varchar(32)

  select @now = case coalesce(@currentDateTime,'') when '' then current_timestamp else @currentDateTime end ,
         @start = max( [DateTime] )
  from dbo.Log
  where ProfileId = @profileId

  set @elapsed = convert(varchar,@now-@start,108)

  insert dbo.Log ( ElapsedTime ) Values (@elapsed);

  return 0
go
```

If your elapsed time might exceed one day, then your original approach is what you want:

```
create procedure dbo.CalculateElaspedTime

  @ProfileID       nvarchar(10)  ,
  @CurrentDateTime datetime = '' 

as

  set nocount on

  declare @now     dateTime = case coalesce(@currentDateTime,'') when '' then current_timestamp else @currentDateTime end ,
  declare @start   datetime = ( select max([DateTime]) from dbo.Log where profileId = @profileId )
  declare @elapsed int      = select datediff(ss,@now,@start)
  declare
    @hh int ,
    @mm int ,
    @ss int

  set @hh      = @elapsed / 3600 -- 3600 is seconds/hour
  set @elapsed = @elapsed % 3600 
  set @mm      = @elapsed / 60   -- 60 is seconds/minute
  set @elapsed = @elapsed % 60
  set @ss      = @elapsed / 1   -- 1 is seconds/second :)

  declare @hhmmss =       right('00'+convert(varchar,@hh),2)
                  + ':' + right('00'+convert(varchar,@mm),2)
                  + ':' + right('00'+convert(varchar,@ss),2)

  insert dbo.Log ( ElapsedTime ) Values (@hhmmss);

  return 0
go
```